# IIS loads wrong php.ini, PHPRC example on PHP.net doesn't work

Tags: php, iis-7

I'm using IIS7's PHP Manager to change php version.

I've installed php5.5 and altered to php.ini file to suit my server.

However, when I attach the handler, the server continues to use the old config file.

It tries to use `D:\php\php.ini`, but it should be using `D:\php5.5\php.ini.`

I've tried using the shell script on PHP.net ([example #9 here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php)) but have had no sucess.

**How do you tell php to use this other php.ini file?**

edit: I tried setting the PHPRC environment variable, but that hasn't worked either, even after a server restart.

Comment: this belongs on serverfault.

Comment: ooo thanks, wasn't even aware of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah no worries,

I just needed to reset my environment variables in `System->Advanced Settings->Environment Variables->System variables`